# Using the same object while using the connection from the dataSource

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, connection, datasource, jdbctemplate

```
beginTx() {
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
SingleConnectionDataSource scd = new SingleConnectionDataSource(conn, true);
SimpleJdbcTemplate template = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(scd);
}
```

I would like to reuse scd and template without having to create new scd and templates. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a bean and inject it like:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        p:url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/extension" 
        p:username="user"
        p:password="pass" 
        />
```

But keep in mind as the [doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/SingleConnectionDataSource.html) specifies that this is primarily intended for testing and it is not working well in multi-threaded environment.

Comment: What would you suggest for using in Multi-Threaded environment and which is equally efficient?